# OpenCV poor performance of Haar classifier trained by me

Tags: opencv, classification, cascade, haar-classifier

I would like to use the Haar classifier to detect the presence of vehicles in a scene (trying with only cars so far). Since I have not found many trained XML files online, I decided to generate my own.

I found some image sets of vehicles that have been used for similar purposes (training computer vision algorithms) and used these to create my own XML files. It has been almost a week and some of them have finished, so I tried using them but the results were terrible. The classifiers I found online worked decently, at least it appears they are trying to detect vehicles and work fast enough for real-time application (maybe 5-10 FPS or so).

Whereas mine can take several minutes to analyze a frame using detectMultiScale() using the same parameters, and if I pass different parameters (e.g. increase min size, decrease max size, increase scaling factor) it will work faster (maybe 1 FPS) but detects absolutely nothing of note, never detects any vehicle and randomly detects some spots of asphalt as a vehicle.

Where did I go wrong in generating my files? I have limited time to complete this task and these classifiers can take a whole week to train so I have very few attempts remaining. For reference, my methodology is (following [this](http://opencvuser.blogspot.ca/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html) tutorial):

-Take all positive and negative images; if no negative images supplied, take negative images from another data set, at least as many negatives as positives

-Generate as many samples as the number of positives

-Use same parameters as suggested, except image size (set to the size of images in a given data set), and nstages (set to 10 because 20 takes far too long)

-For the npos parameter, I use 1/10th the number of samples, using the full number of samples resulted in "assertion failed" after a few hours, apparently the number of samples cannot be the same as the npos according to [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/3085/why-always-opencv-error-assertion-failed-elements_read-1-in-unknown-function/) so I gave myself a safety margin.

**TL;DR Haar classifier I trained myself performs much worse than one found online (in terms of time and accuracy), need advice on how to improve it and not waste another week training it.**

Comment: npos should be around 90% of your positive samples for 20 stages and minHitRate of 0.995. That yozr classifier needs so much timr for detection is a hint that is too complrx because of oversampling. Can you post some of your positive samples please?

Comment: I have found a [project](https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades) on Github that seems to do exactly what you're looking for, based on this [post](https://www.behance.net/gallery/4057777/Vehicle-Detection-Tracking-and-Counting). Apparently, it provides a `cars.xml` file that is used to train the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here. One, the accuracy of the classifier is low. The other, the classifier runs too slow.

There seems to be no problem with the reference that you used. The steps seem accurate, and I have personally tried them in that order and managed to get good results.

As @Micka mentions, nPos around 90% of the original sample count is good enough. minHitRate is a parameter that you can change. Did you observe the numbers that are displayed while training? How was the accuracy improving, and did your classifier stop training (or are you using the trained parameters before learning ends?)?

For the low speed in detection, the most likely reason is that your training data did not have simple features to learn quickly. Did you trying detection on the data that you used for training? How were the results in that case? Compiler settings or high image resolution can be a problem too, but if you tried the same inputs and settings with other classifiers, this is unlikely.

If you like tor try a different approach (and have a GPU), YOLO V2 should be much faster and more accurate for this task.